# Why phase lag on helicopter blade is sometimes 90°, and sometimes less?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter, blade

On semi rigid rotor head, phase lag is 90°, and also the advance angle between pitch link and coresponding blade. But of fully articulated rotor the phase lag is less then 90°, and also the advance angle.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_lag_(rotorcraft)) proposes an answer.

Comment: How much are you actually comfortable with the concepts of mechanical oscillation, natural frequency and resonance? Just to tailor the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's a clear, intuitive answer to this, you'll have to consider the math to some extent.  I've attempted to explain that below.  In short, a fully articulated rotor has a flap hinge offset from the center of the hub which effectively "stiffens" the blade in flap dynamics and increases flap frequency.  This causes peak flapping to occur more quickly after an applied force/moment.

A **semirigid rotor** flaps "freely" about a hinge at the center of the hub.  The force limiting flapping is the component of the centrifugal force perpendicular to the blade.  The centrifugal force CF pushes away from the axis of rotation/shaft.

When a blade is at 0 flapping angle the CF just stretches the blade outward, it does not push it up/down in flapping.  However, when a blade flaps up to an angle $\beta$ a component of the CF pushes it blade back down: $CF*\sin\beta$.  Vice versa when it flaps down.

I'll omit details of the math because you can find that here:
[Basic Flap Dynamics](https://www.spinningwing.com/the-helicopter/basic-flap-dynamics).  In short, with rotor speed $\Omega$, this results in a differential equation $\ddot{\beta}=-\Omega^2 \beta$ whose solution is a 1/rev flapping frequency (it's just like a simple spring/mass system).  Furthermore, adding a flap moment to this equation at a particular azimuth results in a peak flap angle 90 degrees later.

The math is different for a **fully articulated rotor**, because the flap hinge is offset from the center of the hub.  Moving the flap hinge outward decreases both the flap inertia of a blade and the moment due to CF.  However, it decreases the inertia more than the CF and therefore increases flap acceleration and "stiffens" the blade in flap motion.  The differential equation therefore results in a higher frequency solution.

Again you can see the details [here](https://www.spinningwing.com/the-helicopter/basic-flap-dynamics).  Since there's more acceleration toward 0 flapping, the flap response to an external force/moment will generally be smaller and occur sooner, within 90 degrees.  The precise number depends on how far the hinge is from the center of the hub.

Answer (score 2):

I enclose some text from 'Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics' by Gordon Leishman, on the subject:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be better to copy the text here, in case the links go stale.

Comment: Right... Done...